# Input form for batch with HTA

Tags: user-interface, batch-file, cmd, hta

How can I make a simple input form in HTA and read it Batch in a simple variable,
and a button to proceed. I don't know any other way to make a decent GUI for a batch file.
Something like this

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your batch do exactly ?

Comment: Someone need to input a serial number and the batch search for the specific file by name and print it , i had that going . I only need a input type where it has to type the SN and press next and then the batch does the rest

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46206106/edit) your question and add your batch code !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, all you need to do is

- Get a reference to the standard output stream inside the `.hta` file and write to this output the content of the field
- Execute the `.hta` from batch file using a `for /f` command to process the data sent to standard output.

The only *"problem"* is that you need to explicitly call the `mshta.exe` executable with the full path to the `.hta` file.

*serialNumber.hta*

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <HTA:APPLICATION 
            ID              = "serialHTA" 
            APPLICATIONNAME = "serialHTA"
            VERSION         = "0.1"
            NAVIGABLE       = "yes"
            SHOWINTASKBAR   = "yes" 
            SINGLEINSTANCE  = "yes" 
            WINDOWSTATE     = "normal"

            BORDER          = "normal" 
            BORDERSTYLE     = "normal"
            INNERBORDER     = "no" 

            CAPTION         = "yes" 
            MINIMIZEBUTTON  = "yes"
            MAXIMIZEBUTTON  = "yes"
            SYSMENU         = "yes" 
            SCROLL          = "yes" 
            SCROLLFLAT      = "yes"

            CONTEXTMENU     = "yes"
            SELECTION       = "yes"
        />

        <TITLE>input serial number</TITLE>

        <SCRIPT language="Javascript">
            function closeHTA(sendOutput){
                if (sendOutput){
                    (new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'))
                        .GetStandardStream(1)
                        .WriteLine(
                            document.getElementById('serialNumber').value
                        );
                };
                window.close();
            }
        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <label for="serialNumber">serial:</label>
        <input type="text" id="serialNumber">
        <br>
        <button onclick="closeHTA(true);">ok</button>
        <button onclick="closeHTA();">cancel</button>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

*serialNumber.cmd*

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "serialNumber="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~dp0\serialnumber.hta"') do set "serialNumber=%%a"

    if defined serialNumber (
        echo Serial number: %serialNumber%
    ) else (
        echo No serial number provided
    )
```

Comment: Thank you , that's exactly what i was looking for , but how can i resize the hta window like w:400 h:200 ?

Comment: got it with <script type="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(300,290);
</script>

Comment: @RaduMihai You can also take a look at this neat thread [Using "HTA input forms" in Batch files](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6581&sid=76dbeb2030434ebec5c62a97641920af)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can run it from one file like so

```html
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "serialNumber="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "serialNumber=%%a"

    if defined serialNumber echo %serialNumber%
pause
-->
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <HTA:APPLICATION 
            ID              = "serialHTA" 
            APPLICATIONNAME = "serialHTA"
            VERSION         = "0.1"
            NAVIGABLE       = "yes"
            SHOWINTASKBAR   = "yes" 
            SINGLEINSTANCE  = "yes" 
            WINDOWSTATE     = "normal"

            BORDER          = "normal" 
            BORDERSTYLE     = "normal"
            INNERBORDER     = "no" 

            CAPTION         = "yes" 
            MINIMIZEBUTTON  = "yes"
            MAXIMIZEBUTTON  = "yes"
            SYSMENU         = "yes" 
            SCROLL          = "yes" 
            SCROLLFLAT      = "yes"

            CONTEXTMENU     = "yes"
            SELECTION       = "yes"
        />

        <TITLE>input serial number</TITLE>

        <SCRIPT language="Javascript">
            function closeHTA(sendOutput){
                if (sendOutput){
                    (new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'))
                        .GetStandardStream(1)
                        .WriteLine(
                            document.getElementById('serialNumber').value
                        );
                };
                window.close();
            }
        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <label for="serialNumber">serial:</label>
        <input type="text" id="serialNumber">
        <br>
        <button onclick="closeHTA(true);">ok</button>
        <button onclick="closeHTA();">cancel</button>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Cool idea. I tried to run it and got an error 'File Handle is invalid' on line 42:                   (new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')).GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(document.getElementById('serialNumber').value);